# Copied Delphi projects doesn't use new directory

Tags: delphi, copy

Delphi Rio.  I have a project I have worked on called PasteParser.  I am now wanting to create a new project called Clarity which is similar to PasteParser.  So outside of Delphi, I copy the PasteParser entire directory structure to a directory called Clarity. I start Delphi, and open the project CALLED PasteParser in the Clarity directory.  I right click on the project name, and select rename.  I save, close the project, and reopen...The project now has the right name, and I am thinking all is good.  I move a few buttons around, compile and then run.  What comes up is the ORIGINAL program.  What I am finding is that even though I have a new directory, and a new project, the project seems to have hard-coded the PasteParser directory into the files the the project uses.  I look at Clarity Project Source, and none of the files have a hard coded directory.

Why is the Clarity project still using the Main.pas, etc. files from the PasteParser project?

*** FOLLOWUP: The only place (to my knowledge) which shows what files are in the project is the *.dpr file.  Here is the file contents.  Note that the glib_* files are correct in their location.  The remaining files do NOT have a directory listed, so they should be using the Clarity directory, yet they are not.

Here is the View/Project Source listing...
program Clarity;

```
uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  MainPas in 'MainPas.pas' {Main},
  ParserUtils in 'ParserUtils.pas',
  ParserGlobals in 'ParserGlobals.pas',
  helpPas in 'helpPas.pas' {help_form},
  FormatsWinPas in 'FormatsWinPas.pas' {FormatsForm},
  ParseContacts in 'V1\ParseContacts.pas',
  ParseOpps in 'V1\ParseOpps.pas',
  ParseSalesActivities in 'V1\ParseSalesActivities.pas',
  ParseSR in 'V1\ParseSR.pas',
  Parse_IB_TABLE in 'V2\Parse_IB_TABLE.pas',
  StatusBar_Utils in 'StatusBar_Utils.pas',
  RB_Class in 'RB_Class.pas',
  glib_excel in 'D:\VCL_RIO\MISC\GLIB2\glib_excel.pas',
  glib_globals in 'D:\VCL_RIO\MISC\GLIB2\glib_globals.pas',
  glib_utils in 'D:\VCL_RIO\MISC\GLIB2\glib_utils.pas',
  glib_ORCL in 'D:\VCL_RIO\MISC\GLIB2\glib_ORCL.pas';
```

Comment: You'll need to look at the project files. We can't tell you what they say.

Comment: David - I added the file portion of the clarity.dpr file.

Comment: I suggest you also look at / compare with the `.dproj` file.

Comment: You should carefully check your project options of your copied project. It is possible that some of the paths are defined as absolute paths instead of relative paths. This can easily happen when you chose the either Output or source directory by clicking on three dots which then open directory selection dialog. This also happens if you add a unit to a project using Add command from a project menu context menu that you get by right-clicking on project. So it is possible that your copied project is recompiling the files at location of your original project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work is by opening my project, and then in the projects window (which lists all of my pas/dfm files), right click on each of the pas files and choose 'Save As', and giving it the new location.

Comment: While you can do that, the most easy answer is to delete the *.dsk file(s) in the copied project folder!

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete all *.dproj.local, *.identcache, *.dsk from the new project directory

Comment: plus 1 for deleting *.dsk file(s)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It contains [Modules] section, which lists all previously opened files (incl. full path) . So the user could think he is editing a file from the new folder, but it is not.

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem when using dsk files and one copies a project to another place!